# Populate Listview without DataSource/Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Just for background: So Im trying to create an interface for users to check-in. The concept is simple:A Listview where each item holds an image, name, some info, and a button to the right that says check-in (That they'd press). 
This interface is on a webpage (.aspx) with an .aspx.cs codefile.

I've created my ListView & set templates

```
<asp:ListView
    ID="lvInstructors"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ShowRegularGridWhenEmpty="False"
    EmptyDataText="No Sessions to Display."
    OnRowDataBound="lvDataBound"
    OnRowCommand="lvCommand"
    Visible="true">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="container" id="mainContent">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row instructorItem">
            <div class="col-2 sessionStartTimeDiv">
                <p class="sessionStartTime"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2 instructorHeadshotDiv">
                <asp:Image class="instructorHeadshot" runat="server" src="" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-5 sessionInfoDiv">
                <h3 class="instructorName"></h3>
                <p class="sessionInfo"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3 checkInBtnDiv">
                <asp:Button class="checkInBtn" OnClick="CheckInBtn_Click" ID="checkInBtn" runat="server" Text="CHECK-IN" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <EmptyDataTemplate>No Sessions to Display</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

My issue is, I don't want to link this ListView to a database, source, or table (Is that even possible)

Below are the variables in .aspx.cs that I'd like to populate my ListView Items with, but Im not sure how to go about doing do, especially when it comes to creating a new ListView Item per each for loop. Any suggestions? Thanks Alot!

```
foreach (Session S in UpcomingSessions)
{
    foreach(Enrollment I in S.Instructors())
    {
        SessionName = S.Name;
        SessionStartTime = S.FirstDateTime().ToShortTimeString();
        InstructorName = I.FirstName + " " + I.LastName;
        SessionRoom = S.Room.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also bind an IEnumerable / List. https://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/07/22/when-to-use-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-and-list/. Like `lvInstructors.DataSrouce = UpcomingSessions;`

Comment: Thank You, VDWWD. Will look into it & try it out. Didn't know I also had that kind of flexibility with the DataSource

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
public class Instructors{
 public string SessionName{get;set;}
 public DateTime SessionStartTime {get;set;}
 public string InstructorName {get;set;}
 public string SessionRoom {get;set;}
}

List<Instructors>  InstructorsLst=new List<Instructors>();   

foreach (Session S in UpcomingSessions)
{
 foreach(Enrollment I in S.Instructors())
 {
   Instructors inst=new Instructors();
    inst.SessionName = S.Name;
    inst.SessionStartTime = S.FirstDateTime().ToShortTimeString();
    inst.InstructorName = I.FirstName + " " + I.LastName;
    inst.SessionRoom = S.Room.ToString();

    InstructorsLst.Add(inst);
 }
}

lvInstructors.DataSrouce = InstructorsLst;
lvInstructors.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks alot, A A. The solution that I got to work was very similar to this.